# jQuery errors in Wordpress admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am not at all an expert in jQuery, so I don't know how to go about making sense of the errors I'm getting on my Wordpress admin pages (I'm also experiencing odd behavior on the front end that I suspect is associated with jQuery, but I don't have any error messages showing up in Chrome inspector). The first error on the admin side is "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined," which Chrome tells me is coming from this line of code:

`function(a) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : a(jQuery)
}`

Here is a screen grab of all the errors showing up in inspector:
[image: jQuery error messages in Chrome inspector]

I honestly don't even know where to begin diagnosing the source of the jQuery errors, but will happily update this question with more info that anyone requests.

Comment: Obvious question is have you recently changed anything that might have created a problem...including upgrades, new plugins etc

Comment: Not as obvious as it should have been! Thanks @charlietfl - that helped me get to the source of the problem. I thought I had gone through that step already, but apparently I missed the plugin that was causing the jQuery issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a buried set of jQuery options included with one of the plugins on the site. Disabling the plugins one-by-one allowed me to figure out the offending plugin, then tinker with the settings until the errors went away.